ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value cant migrate python file
I am not able to migrate my changes.
when i run python manage.py runserver -
Full Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\manage.py", line 22, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 442, in
execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management_init_.py", line 436, in
execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 459, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 107, in wrapper
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line
117, in handle
executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in init
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in init
self.build_graph()
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
if self.has_table():
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 316, in cursor
return self._cursor()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\kshitijb\Desktop\Income-Expense-Tracker\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 20, in complain
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
seetings.py
DB_NAME = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB") #database name
DB_USER_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD") # database user password
DB_USER = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER") # database username
DB_HOST = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST") # database host
# POSTGRES_PORT = os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT") # database port


POSTGRES_READY = (
    DB_NAME is not None
    and DB_USER_PASSWORD is not None
    and DB_USER is not None
    and DB_HOST is not None
)

print(POSTGRES_READY)

if POSTGRES_READY:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': DB_NAME,
            'USER': DB_USER,
            'PASSWORD': DB_USER_PASSWORD,
            'HOST': DB_HOST,
        }
    }

.env -
export DB_NAME=<DB_NAME>
export DB_USER=<DB_USER>
export DB_USER_PASSWORD=<DB_USER_PASSWORD>
export DB_HOST=localhost

export CLOUD_NAME=<CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME>
export API_KEY=<CLOUDINARY_API_KEY>
export API_SECRET=<CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET>
export SECRET_KEY=<CLOUDINARY_SECRET_KEY>
export SENTRY_DSN='<SENTRY_DSN_URL>'


Your .env file has DB_HOST, but your code is looking for POSTGRES_HOST.  And the same with the other variables for user, password, etc.

What did it display for print(POSTGRES_READY) ?

And I think your .env file format is wrong anyway.  It shouldn't have export in front of each line.

How, exactly, are you using the .env file?  Django doesn't automatically load that file.  How are you loading it?

This should work in my case
.env file
# Database settings
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
DB_NAME=dn_name
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432

setting.py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": os.environ.get("DB_ENGINE", "django.db.backends.postgresql"),
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
    }
}

i would remove this part of code
POSTGRES_READY = (
    DB_NAME is not None
    and DB_USER_PASSWORD is not None
    and DB_USER is not None
    and DB_HOST is not None
)

print(POSTGRES_READY)

if POSTGRES_READY:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': DB_NAME,
            'USER': DB_USER,
            'PASSWORD': DB_USER_PASSWORD,
            'HOST': DB_HOST,
        }
    }


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
